# 3D Classes in a 2D Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, 2d-games, unity3d-2dtools

I have a lot of Unity scripts written for a 3D game that would be useful in a 2D game, and I really don't want to reinvent the wheel to add them to that game.  So my question is, can I use my current 3D game scripts (with Vector3s and calls to Physics.Raycast(), Physics.Gravity, etc.) in a 2D game (where all the GameObjects have 2D components like Collider2D and Rigidbody2D and there will be other scripts using calls to **Physics2D**.Raycast(), **Physics2D**.Gravity, etc.)?  I'm guessing that I *can* do it but that it will be stupid inefficient, so I might as well re-implement with 2D classes.  But figured I'd ask first.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can no problem.  Enjoy.  it's not "stupid inefficient"; 99% of games barely come even close to performance limits.  in practice you'll find it's easy (and fun!) to just modify to the "2D" classes in most cases.

Comment: @Joe Blow. Thanks for ur answer!  Modifying everything to 2d classes is what I'm actually trying to avoid though.  I have a wealth of scripts already written for the 3d game, and I don't want to take the time to copy all of them just to change every Vector3 to a Vector2 and such.  Moreover, these 3d scripts are still under development, so creating a 2d copy would require making every change twice. Are you just recommending that I modify all my 3d scripts for 2d, or do I actually HAVE to do this to make them work in a 2D game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the comment from Joe, you can. There will be no problem since the Unity 2D functions will takes vector2D and when Vector3D is passed into them, z axis will be discarded.

My suggestion is to use the-same Script for **3D** and **2D** as that makes everything easier to work with. For example, when you make big game logic changes in your 3D script, you have to do the-same in 2D script. Also a big pain when you want to troubleshoot your 2D or 3D codes. This is where `C# Preprocessor Directives` should be used.

```
#if USE2D
//Put your 2D specific API code
#else
//Put your 3D specific API code
#endif
```

Now, to test **2D** code, simply put `#define USE2D` at the top of your code. This can be helpful when you want to troubleshoot your **3D** and **2D** codes. You just **comment** `#define USE2D` to test **3D** code and **uncomment** it to test **2D** code.

Comment: Wow, @Programmer, great idea! I never would've thought to use conditional compilation. Do you know if Unity has any built in #defines for this purpose?

Comment: @Rabadash8820 Unity does have many Preprocessor  but they don't have one for 2D/3D. You can add this your self and enable it when you want to build for 2D/3D. Note, you can even use `[Conditional("USE2D")]` instead of `#if USE2D` and that is cleaner. For more information about this,see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96(v=vs.90).aspx . For more information about Unity built in  Preprocessors  see http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html . You can even define it from the editor. Just visit link.

Comment: Awesome links, thank you so much for this elegant solution.  I've marked ur answer as the correct one!